# MySql having multiple sum checking one column

Tags: mysql, case-when

**Table: invoice**

```
id   amount     status  
1    100        PAID    
1    200        PAID    
1    500        UNPAID
1    100        UNPAID
```

I want sum on the basis of status
**Result:**

```
id      paid_amt    unpaid_amt
1       300         600
```

Would you please provide the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need pivoting case, before summing, for the desired result.

Try this:

```
select 
  id,
  sum( paid_amount ) as paid_amount,
  sum( unpaid_amount ) as unpaid_amount
from(
  SELECT
    id,
    case status when 'PAID' then amount else 0 end paid_amount,
    case status when 'UNPAID' then amount else 0 end unpaid_amount
  FROM Invoice
) pay_report
group by id
```